# The APK won't run on the android emulator. (Unfortunately the app has stopped)

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android app development. I wrote an android code for a simple app that on clicking the Add one button, adds 1 to the total in the text field that's supposed to be above the button and on clicking subtract one button, subtracts 1 from the Text field above. Here is the code for it.

```
package com.example.ocrtransbybee;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;

public class StartingPoint extends Activity {

int counter;
Button add, sub;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);



    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });
sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.starting_point, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

And the layout xml code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hey"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    />

<Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Button1"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    />
<Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Button2"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
    />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And the runtime information:

```
[2014-02-16 20:57:49 - OCRTransByBee] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-02-16 20:57:49 - OCRTransByBee] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-02-16 21:00:41 - OCRTransByBee] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'

[2014-02-16 21:00:41 - OCRTransByBee] Uploading OCRTransByBee.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2014-02-16 21:00:42 - OCRTransByBee] Installing OCRTransByBee.apk...

[2014-02-16 21:02:04 - OCRTransByBee] Success!

[2014-02-16 21:02:05 - OCRTransByBee] Starting activity com.example.ocrtransbybee.StartingPoint on device emulator-5554

[2014-02-16 21:02:11 - OCRTransByBee] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.ocrtransbybee/.StartingPoint }
```

It doesn't start in the emulator, the code seems fine to me, it was working fine in the school in my friend's laptop, it says "Unfortunately, the app has stopped" every time I try to run it.

Comment: If you're code is right then try to recreate new emulator and try again

Comment: You have included the wrong part of the logcat output.  Please find the crash and it's stack trace and include that.  If you don't know how, please Google for how to read logcat, then edit your question.

Comment: "You have included the wrong part of the logcat output" -- that's not the LogCat output at all. That's the Eclipse console. LogCat is a separate view within Eclipse.

Comment: change : display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay); (error in casting Textview with a Button )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting `TextView` with a `Button`.

```
TextView display;
```

And you have

```
display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

Should be

```
display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You trying to cast **display(TextView)** object with **Button** Class.

Just replace

`display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);`

with

`display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);`

Comment: tip: for good coding practice create object names like addBtn, subBtn,  etc

Answer (score 0):

There is cast class exception in code.

The problem is in this code of line.

```
display = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```

Change is to

```
display=  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
```